# Separate groups of people based on members

Tags: algorithm

I have groups of people. I need to move groups with at least one same member as far as possible from each other.

Example:

```
GroupA - John, Bob, Nick
GroupB - Jack, Nick
GroupC - Brian, Alex, Steve
```

As you can see GroupA and GroupB overlap(they both contain Nick)
I need an algorithm to set groups as GroupA->GroupC->GroupB

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you define the problem exactly -- with overlaps and costs and things.

This might reduces to [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) -- you can set edge weights as 0 if group `i` and `j` has nothing in common, and some function `f(i,j)` that depends on the number of common items between them.  Then, you want a list that goes from one group to the last group, visiting each group once, minimizing some function of overlap.

You can probably reduce TSP to a version of this (really depending on how specific you mean by "farthest as possible", with regards to competing overlaps) similarly.

Unfortunately, this is [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), which means you should start looking for something that's "good enough".

Comment: Thanks, actually i probably oversimplified the task.
Groups repeat n-times. Like GroupA - 3 times, GroupB - 5 times etc.
So i am looking to trace groups so members wouldn't go 2 times in a row(at least). I guess i need to think through your solution :)

Comment: Agree, this is hamilton path problem. NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not have a unique or even meaningful solution if you have arbitrary groups. See for example:

```
GroupA = {Alice, Bob}
GroupB = {Bob, David}
GroupC = {David, Alice}
```

Comment: Agree, but the lack of solution is also a result. Probably the output would be a recommendation how to change groups to have a solution.